# Multiple Facebook Clients aspnet core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, facebook-authentication, asp.net-authentication

I have two different apps that call the same api in Aspnet Core 2.0.  In the startup code for simplicity I have

```
...
  services.AddAuthentication()
           .AddGoogle(options =>
           {
               options.ClientId = WebConfig.GoogleClientId;
               options.ClientSecret = WebConfig.GoogleClientSecret;
           })
           .AddFacebook(options =>
           {
               options.ClientId = WebConfig.FacebookConsumerClientId;
               options.ClientSecret = WebConfig.FacebookConsumerClientSecret;
               options.SaveTokens = true;
           })
           .AddFacebook(options =>
           {
               options.ClientId = WebConfig.FacebookProviderClientId;
               options.ClientSecret = WebConfig.FacebookProviderClientSecret;
               options.SaveTokens = true;
           })
           .AddOAuthValidation();
```

There is no warning but when I try to run migrations the error says

```
 "scheme already exists:facebook"
```

How do I register multiple facebook clients in Aspnet Core 2.0?  I read in another post that in aspnet core 1.x you could set different schemes.  I can also do that here by adding

```
options.SignInScheme = "facebook1";
```

and for the other

```
options.SignInScheme = "facebook2";
```

but am not sure if there is anything else I need to do?

Comment: @Pinpoint any suggestions?  You seem to know a lot about this.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

As you said you should set different schema name for each authentication. You can do it like this :

```
services.AddAuthentication()
       .AddGoogle(options =>
       {
           options.ClientId = WebConfig.GoogleClientId;
           options.ClientSecret = WebConfig.GoogleClientSecret;
       })
       .AddFacebook("facebook1", options =>
       {
           options.ClientId = WebConfig.FacebookConsumerClientId;
           options.ClientSecret = WebConfig.FacebookConsumerClientSecret;
           options.SaveTokens = true;
       })
       .AddFacebook("facebook2", options =>
       {
           options.ClientId = WebConfig.FacebookProviderClientId;
           options.ClientSecret = WebConfig.FacebookProviderClientSecret;
           options.SaveTokens = true;
       })
       .AddOAuthValidation();
```

Comment: Thanks, do I then need to create custom handlers for each or will it work without those?

Comment: what do you mean by handlers? I think it doesn't need anything more to work